# Running blazor on macOS

Tags: c#, macos, visual-studio, blazor

Is there a way to develop with blazor on mac? I saw the getting started guide and the first problem I saw was that there is no template in the visual studio for mac or ASP.NET Core Blazor Language Services*** extension to be able to run it.

If there is a way can you give me some beginner steps to start a simple project ?

Comment: Isn't it interesting Microsoft has an option for creating a Blazor library, but not an application? Does Microsoft have a drug problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a look at the available templates:
https://github.com/dotnet/templating/wiki/Available-templates-for-dotnet-new

In your case it would be: `dotnet new -i Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.Templates::*`

The [documentation on blazor.net](https://blazor.net/docs/get-started.html) can help you get started, scroll down to where it shows you how to create via command line.

Comment: And then use `dotnet new` command: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-new?tabs=netcore22 - to create a project. Since the templates will still not be visible inside visual studio on mac after installing them.

Comment: It would have been nice if Microsoft added this piece of information on their getting started page.